# Why is source code text-only?

Tags: ide, editor, wysiwyg

All my life I have used text-based source code editors.
I can't believe we're all still doing this!  There must be a better way.

I don't mean that I want to use a WYSIWYG-editor, I usually hate those, since they don't exactly produce what you want.

No, I mean a text-based source-code editor that is greatly enhanced by the following extra's:

- include pictures, excel-data, pdf's, etc. INSIDE the source code, to explain certain data-structures, to include (mockup) screenshots of what the client actually wants, etc. Of course with the option to minify/hide/fold these things. 
  (the advantage of this as opposed to separate file, is clear, you want to store this information together WITH your source code)
- comments not as text, but more like post-it-like items, that are resizable, moveable, clickable, etc.
- Class definitions and instances not as text, but as clickable object-boxes, maybe even with an icon to quickly see in the source code which class an object is).
- operators that are now 2 characters as 1 symbol. For example:  -> in PHP  as a real arrow.
- possibility to use colors, different text sizes and other layout tools inside the source code   (i'm not talking about automatic syntax coloring, sometimes it can be handy to emphasize certain blocks of text by using a layout tools as you do in Word)
- include separate files inside a different file, but still be able to edit/view those as if it were 1 file   (comparable to Adobe Illustrator where you can place separate files inside a document, but still be able to edit them).

I know a lot of hardcore programmers are appalled by these kind of things, but they can still edit the way they want, I just think it would be neat to have those extra possibilities. Why on earth is source code STILL only text, where so many other types of documents are much more complex?

Does anyone know of any source code editor that has some of these features??

Comment: If there was demand, I'm sure someone would create one. I think the problem lies in the first half of this statement.

Comment: I think it has more to do with the fact that most programmers are nerds (no offense!) that have difficulties with more creative ways of working than plain text. But as long as this is the case, programming will always be regarded as something that is too difficult for 'normal' people, which is a bad thing , in my opinion.

Comment: Did you know about http://lighttable.com/ ?

Answer (score 5):

There have been attempts to make visual development tools in the past - but the problem is that computers need very precise statements in a formal language in order to fully meet a specific requirement of a user.

In fact, if you write down a requirement and then read it with different emphasis you will see that it is very hard to write an unambiguous statement.

This example is from Software Craftsmanship: The New Imperative by Pete McBreen (978-0201733860).

> **Mary** had a little lamb - the lamb belongs to Mary and not anybody else
>
> Mary **had** a little lamb - she no longer has it
>
> Mary had **a** little lamb - there was only one
>
> Mary had a **little** lamb - it was exceptionally small
>
> Mary had a little **lamb** - everybody else ate chicken

This is why we need a language that requires us to be more explicit that natural language requires and why visual aids to development are not useful.

For example, being to annotate code with a "post-it" is less useful that writing clean readable code that is easy for other people to read. In fact, sharing code with other developers means changing text size and colour would require other developers to suffer your personal style, which is not cool.

Some of the ideas you mention are actually available now. Being able to view a class diagram and navigate to the code by clicking on the class "boxes" is a feature of Visual Studio - as is organisation of multiple files behind a single file in the tree view.

Answer (score 1):

This is just my opinion of course, so take it with a grain of salt. I think the main reason that something like this hasn't been done is because the compilers still expect plain text. If you have a source code editor like you mention, it's going to be just a front end - the actual source files will still be plain text. The problem that you run into is that each source editor that takes this approach may have a different way of implementing certain features, so what appears to be identical source will in fact be completely different in the plain text.

When you compile that source, you'll be in a world of trouble. It might be fine for the example you mentioned, PHP, but for the type of things that I work on (real-time C++ applications for industry) I need exact low level control over the source so that I know exactly how my code is being compiled. This would never work for the vast majority of programmers, which is why it's never been done. The target audience is small at best.

Comment: OK, but all these things that I mention would only be a layer on top of normal source code. The underlying source code would stll be the same. The extra information doesnt even need to be stored inside the same file as the source code, an extra file with another extension would be just fine. People that have an editor that can read this information can use this then, others can still use the source code as they would do normally (I do realize that altering the source code with a normal editor then would cause trouble, but most development teams use the same tools, I think)

Comment: No, you missed my point. When you are editing a source file with one of these editors it is entirely up to the editor how to implement all these features. It would be difficult to know how the editor is actually saving the source code on the back end. It may have a separate file (sort of like visual studio does with the .suo) and keep the source plain text exactly the same, but now you have two files to keep track of. Are you going to check both in to version control? Basically, my point is that I just don't see many developers actually USING this type of editor. No demand, no product.

Comment: Well, some of the things I mention could be done by a smartly formatted comment block.  Normal editors would display this as a comment then, and advanced editors would display all the extra cool stuff. Pictures could be saved as separate files, but be displayed in the advanced editor as internal picture. But don't you agree that plain text is a little bit stone-age technology? An Excel-file is not a comma separated TEXT anymore. When you want all complex options and funcionality,  it's a complex binary format, and everybody is fine with that. Why couldn't this be the case with source code?

Comment: I agree that what you're asking for is useful for SOME environments and languages, and most of it is implemented in IDEs for those languages. However, plain text is going to remain king because it's what the compilers take as input. If you develop a compiler that reads in symbols other than plain text you will see development environments built to support that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds a lot like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming to me.

There has been some progress on this and some of this is useful right now

#### Fonts with ligatures (and editors with support for them)

[image: Java source code with -> and != rendered as symbols]

(https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode in https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

#### Jupyter Notebook, though you cannot easily "tangle" an executable or library for end-users out of it.

[image: Jypyter Notebook screenshot from their website]

(http://jupyter.org/)

#### Fortress (programming language from Sun)

Fortress supported source code in utf-8 and encouraged its use, esp. for user-defined operators. They experimented with typesetting the source in editors (since most of it was computational science, so lots of math).

#### Elastic tabstops

[image: Elastic tabstops demo from its website]

(http://nickgravgaard.com/elastic-tabstops/)

## Conclusion

There is many efforts like that, actually. There is not yet anything like UX movement for developer tooling, but I have hope it will gather momentum in the coming years.